# How to sort flipkart with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automated-tests

I want to sort flipkart products by popularity but I can't find a way to do it

```
>span class="_2i7N3j">Sort By</span\
>span class="_2i7N3j">Relevance</span\
>span class="_2i7N3j">Popularity</span
```

I want to click popularity

All the option have same class and no id
I also tried with link_text but it didn't work
can someone help

this is the code I wrote

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

product = input("Which product review you want: ").lower()
print(f"Best {product} in your range from famous website")

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

try:
    driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/")
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"q"))
    )
    search.send_keys(product)
    search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    pop = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH("//div[contains(text(), 'Popularity')]")))
    )
    pop.click()
    print(driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(2)

finally:
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: What is the URL of this?

Comment: https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptop&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=off&as=off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can click it like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(r"https://www.flipkart.com/search?q=laptop&otracker=search&otracker1=search&marketplace=FLIPKART&as-show=off&as=off")
time.sleep(3)
popularity_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Popularity')]")
popularity_button.click()
```

The class name is very likely to change in the future, so looking for the text will be more reliable.